# How to solve Swift FileManager couldn’t open file because of permission and implement file access

Tags: swift, macos, apple-developer

I made a music app for macOS that need the access of the file on disk. I can get the proper url, but I can't access the file. To figure out that problem, here I create a concise code snippet to concentrate on the question itself.

```
.onAppear {
    var url = FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser
    url.appendPathComponent("Downloads/Test.txt")
                
    var text: String = ""
                
    do {
        text = try String(contentsOf: url)
    } catch {
        print("ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

The output would be like this
`ERROR: The file “Test.txt” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.`. So I noticed `App Sandbox` in `Targets > Signing & Capabilities`. But at the list of file access (as you can see in the following picture), there's only `User Selected File`, `Downloads Folder`, `Pictures Folder`, `Music Folder` and `Movie Folder`. So I come up with 3 questions:

1. What that `User Selected File` means? Is that means that the user can select some specific file for my app to access? If it is, how can user selects them?
2. How can I get access to other folders like `Desktop Folder` if I remain the `App Sandbox` capability here?
3. I also noticed the trash icon on right-upper corner. If I delete `App Sandbox`, I can access every folder I want with the user's agreement by a default system pop-up. But what the deletion of `App Sandbox` means? Does it make my app "untrusted" somehow when user install it or others? Does it cause any security problems?

And It couldn't be better if you can tell me the conventions major developers follow when meet this problem. I would highly appreciate your help.

[image: Screenshot of app sandbox]

Comment: 1) User selected means they pick the file via a system-presented file chooser `NSOpenPanel` for example 3) If you don't sandbox your app, you can't, for example, release it via the App Store.

Comment: To add to that, `NSOpenPanel` is actually pretty magic. Although your app starts the process of opening it, and it looks like it belongs to your app, it actually doesn't. An OS XPC service starts, which will present the open dialogue on behalf of your app. When the user picks something, the OS will make a security-scoped bookmark and give it to your app. In essence, when Sandboxed, the OS is the full gate-keeper to all filesystem access outside of those few folders like downloads, pictures, etc.